# Iterate using Array.forEach in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I want to use this Fluid Player function for each video with the same class name. I heard that I can do it using the `Array.forEach()` method, but I have no idea how.

I have also tried using a normal `for` loop, and executing the Fluid Player function on every array element but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.css" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
 <video class = "classname" id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="deja vu.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
 <video class = "classname" id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="deja vu.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
 <video class = "classname" id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="deja vu.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var array = document.getElementByClassName('classname');
Array.forEach(); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Ehh ... can you tell us what you want to do in the iteration? Also, `getElementByClassName` doesn't return an array, it returns a HTMLCollection object. Though that object has `forEach` method in modern browsers.

Comment: on array that i made using getElementByClassName function

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, maybe documentation of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) helps ..?

Comment: So is it even possible to do it the way im using now?

Comment: Can you explain what action do you want to perform on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but we've no clue what you want to do in the iteration loop.

Comment: I want too execute function fluidplayer on every video to play them in custom video player. Videos class name will be stored in array that i made using getElementByClassName.

Comment: Your current `fluidPlayer(` call doesn't seem to take any arguments related to elements, though...

Comment: Then you pass a reference to that function: `array.forEach(fluidplayer);` Notice, the small "a" in "array", i.e. you've to perform the forEach method on the object itself, not with the Array constructor function. Also, one more time, `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array, it returns an object.

Comment: As far as i know i can activate function fluidPlayer() by giving video id which i set(in this case im using 'short'). It activate only one video to play in custom player but rest  are playing in deafult broswre player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the same ID for all videos which you want to use with Fluid Player. Aside from being bad practice (element IDs should be unique), Fluid Player only works with the ID so these IDs need to be different. You're also using the non-existant `getElementByClassName()`, you need to use `getElementsByClassName()`.

`getElementsByClassName()` doesn't actually return an array, it returns a `HTMLCollection`, which isn't exactly the same. You want to use `for x of y` instead.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
    <video class="videoClass" id="short1" height="225" loop  controls> 
        <source src="deja vu.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
    <video class="videoClass" id="short2" height="225" loop  controls> 
        <source src="deja vu.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
    <video class="videoClass" id="short3" height="225" loop  controls> 
        <source src="deja vu.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var vidCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('videoClass');
for (let vidElement of vidCollection) {
    fluidPlayer(
        vidElement.id,
        {
            layoutControls: {
                fillToContainer: false,
                primaryColor: false,
                posterImage: false,
                autoPlay: false,
                playButtonShowing: true,
                playPauseAnimation: true,
                mute: false,
                logo: {
                  imageUrl: null,
                  position: 'top left',
                  clickUrl: null,
                  opacity: 1,
                  mouseOverImageUrl: null,
                  imageMargin: '2px',
                  hideWithControls: false,
                  showOverAds: false
                },
                htmlOnPauseBlock: {
                  html: null,
                  height: null,
                  width: null
                },
                allowDownload: false,
                allowTheatre: false,
                playbackRateEnabled: false,
                controlBar: {
                  autoHide: true,
                  autoHideTimeout: 1,
                  animated: false
                },
            },
            vastOptions: {}
        }
    );
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I got this king of message in console log
Uncaught TypeError: vidArray.forEach is not a function

Comment: Can you try it again with the updated class name of `videoClass` in `getElementsByClassName()`?

Comment: Sorry but i cant understand  what you mean by it. Im using same class name in getElementsByClassName() as in video html tags.

Comment: Ah - my mistake, getElementsByClassName doesn't return an array, it returns a HTMLCollection, which isn't *exactly* the same. You want to use `let x of y` instead - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nice, it's working now. Thanks you very nuch for your help :)

Comment: @F.Hand No problem. Just a note - ID attributes should never really be the same throughout a document, as they are usually used as an *identifier* for a particular element.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question is a bit confusing

*"I want to use this fluidplayer function to every video with the same class name"*

to do what with every classname?

in terms of forEach.

forEach is a method that takes a function, you can either pass it a function to run on the iterations of the target array or you can include an arrow function or anonymous function like this:

```
array.forEach(classname => console.log(classname))
```

// if array = [1,2,3,4] then this will return 1 2 3 and 4 on seperate lines.

Each element of the 'array' array will be iterated over and the function will be called once for each element, passing the element into the function as 'classname' from where we can do whatever we want with it.
Your array is called 'array' so we are using the prototype method forEach that exists on every javascript array. We don't need to use Array. although there are some methods that work this way (Array.isArray(array) for example would return true)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray